# Как из массива взять данные и закинуть в атрибут href?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
let S_NAMES = [
    {name: 'name1', ico: '/img/services/ico/1.svg', about: 'About1', site: 'https://site-1.com'},
    {name: 'name2', ico: '/img/services/ico/2.svg', about: 'About2', site: 'https://site-2.com'},
    {name: 'name3', ico: '/img/services/ico/3.svg', about: 'About3', site: 'https://site-3.com'}];
```

Хочу взять информацию из `site`, и закинуть их в ссылку с классом `.site` в атрибут href, сижу уже 2 час, не могу понять.
Вся эта информация находится в таблице, хотя это не важно.

Вот к примеру остальное я вот так заполнял:

```
 let servicesNames = S_NAMES;
    let cards = ArrServicesName();
    let cardsAbout = ArrServicesAbout();
    let cardsSite = ArrServicesSite();
    let limit = cards.length;
    let shownUserIndexes = [];

    function ArrServicesAbout(){
       let cardsAbout = document.querySelectorAll('.services__about');
       let arr = [];

       for( let i = 0; i < cardsAbout.length; i++ ){
           let card = cardsAbout[i];
           arr.push({
           about: card.querySelector('.services__about-text'),
           });
       }

    return arr; // Google. → JS array reduce

     }
    loadUserData(0, 3);
    function loadUserData(start, end, array){
        array = array || S_NAMES; 

        for( let i = start; i < end; i++ ){
            let index = i % limit; 

            cards[index].ico.src = array[i].ico;
            cards[index].name.textContent = array[i].name;
            cardsAbout[index].about.textContent = array[i].about;

            shownUserIndexes[index] = i;
        }
      }
```

Comment: не понятна суть вопроса, закинуть только первое значение в первую ссылку? или закидывать значения по-порядку во все `.site`?

Comment: По порядку, нужно чтобы name1 стал в первую ссылку в таблице, name2 во вторую и так далее...

Comment: Дополнил. Проверю Ваш код чуть позже, заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let S_NAMES = [{
    name: 'name1',
    ico: '/img/services/ico/1.svg',
    about: 'About1',
    site: 'https://site-1.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    ico: '/img/services/ico/2.svg',
    about: 'About2',
    site: 'https://site-2.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    ico: '/img/services/ico/3.svg',
    about: 'About3',
    site: 'https://site-3.com'
  }
];


[...document.querySelectorAll('a.site')].forEach((link, index) => {
  link.setAttribute('href', S_NAMES[index].site);
});
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="site">1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="site">2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="site">3</a>
```